# Big-O of algorithm

Tags: big-o

I have a quite simple problem, however I am a bit unsure of what the actual runtime (e.g. Big-O) is of this.

The program looks like this.

```
n <- user input
for i=1 to n
    foo(i)

foo a:
for i=1 to a
    foo2()
```

foo2 does an near constant amount of work which is not going to be significant.

What is the Big-O of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each integer 0 <= i <= n, there's another loop which goes 0 <= j <= i.

So, the i-th integer requires i calls to `foo2()`.

Over n integers, this adds up to an average of (n / 2) extra calls to `foo2()` per integer -

`n + (n - 1) + ... + 1 + 0` is the same as

`n + (n - 1 + 1) + ... + (n - n/2 + n/2)`, or

`n * (n / 2)`.

Since the upper bound on complexity is `n^2 / 2,` its growth will happen as quickly as `n^2` - so the complexity is `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming the inner function `foo2()` is Θ(1))

It's Θ(n^2), because the outer loop is executed once for all `i=1...n` with the inner loop being iterated `i` times per outer loop iteration, that makes in total `sum(i) from i=1 to n` executions of `foo2()`, which is equal to `(n+1)*n/2 = 1/2*n^2+1/2*n` times.

Θ(n^2) implies O(n^2).